# quickest way to select/copy lines containing string from huge txt.gz file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

So I have the following `sed` one liner:

```
sed -e '/^S|/d' -e '/^T|/d' -e '/^#D=/d' -e '/^##/d' -e 's/H|/,H|/g' -e 's/Q|/,,Q|/g' -e '1 i\,,,' sample_1.txt > sample_2.txt
```

I have many lines that start with either:

- `S|`
- `T|`
- `#D=`
- `##`
- `H|`
- `Q|`

The idea is to *not* copy the lines starting with one of the first fours and 
to replace `H|` (at the beginning of lines) by `,H|` and `Q|` (at the beginning of lines) by `,,Q|`

But now I would need to:

- use the fastest way possible (internet suggests (m)awk is faster than sed)
- read from a .txt.gz file and save the result in a .txt.gz file, avoiding, if possible, the intermediate un-zip/re-zip

there are in fact several hundreds .txt.gz files, each about ~1GB, to process in this way (all in the same folder). Is there a CLI way to run the code on parallel on all of them (so each core will get assigned a subset of the files in the directory)?

--I use linux --ubuntu

Comment: *"I have many lines that start with either: ... `^#D=`"* - is that a typo? Are those the only line beginnings or can there be others? Are the files ~1GB compressed or uncompressed? If the former, how big uncompressed?

Comment: @haukex: `^#D=` that was a type (fixed now, thanks!). Compressed files are ~1GB each, uncompressed about 20 times more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but likely pretty close to this with **GNU Parallel**.

First make output directory so as not to overwrite any valuable data:

```
mkdir -p output
```

Now declare a function that does one file and export it to subprocesses so jobs started by **GNU Parallel** can find it:

```
doit(){
    echo Processing $1
    gzcat "$1" | awk '
        /^[ST]\|/ || /^#D=/ || /^##/ {next}    # ignore lines starting S|, T| etc
        /^H\|/ {print ","}                     # prefix "H|" with ","
        /^Q\|/ {print ",,"}                    # prefix "Q|" with ",,"
        1                                      # print all other lines
    ' | gzip > output/"$1"
}
export -f doit
```

Now process all `txt.gz` files in parallel and show progress bar too:

```
parallel --bar doit ::: *txt.gz
```

Comment: thanks, this works really great. For future users, I had to replace `gzcat` by `gunzip -c` in ubuntu...

Comment: Small comment: to get the desired output, I replaced `{print ","} ` by `{print ","$0}` and `{print ",,"}` by `{print ",,"$0} `  (probably my question was not clear on that point)

Comment: quick question: do you think this could have been done quicker using `grep`? (I'm still learning these stream tricks)

Comment: No, I don't think so. `awk` is extremely fast and capable. I suspect the bulk of the time is spent recompressing the output. In fact, try it. Replace the `| gzip ...` with `> /dev/null` and see how long the `awk` takes without recompressing.

Answer (score 1):

Was something like this what you had in mind?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export LC_ALL=C

zcat sample_1.txt.gz | gawk '
$1 !~ /^([ST]\||#D=|##)/ {
    switch ($0) {
        case /^H\|/:
            print "," $0
            break
        case /^Q\|/:
            print ",," $0
            break
        default:
            print $0
    }
}' | gzip > sample_2.txt.gz
```

The `export LC_ALL=C` tells your environment you aren't expecting extended characters, and can profoundly speed up execution.  `zcat` expands and dumps a gz file to stdout.  That is piped into `gawk`, which checks that the first part of each line does not match the first four character groupings you have in your question.  For lines that pass that test, output to stdout (massaged as requested).  As `gawk` executes, its stdout gets piped into `gzip` and written to a .txt.gz file.

It might be possible to use `xargs` with the `-P` and `-n` switches to parallelize your processing, but I think [GNU `parallel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28361402/1683264) might be easier to work with.