# How to iterate over thousands of tar balls and pull out a single file with .vcf.gz extension?

Tags: bash, unix, tar

So I have a directory of thousands of tar balls in Unix. I want to iterate over all those tar balls and extract a specific file (uniquely appended with .vcf.gz), out of each tar ball and move it to a different directory?

I can't figure out how to do this effectively. Please help.

Comment: Please be more precise about how you have the names of the files stored and how you deduce the names of the output directories. Thank you.

Comment: the file i want *.vcf.gz exists within the tar ball. The tar is named *_output.tar.gz, within that there is a directory called ./results in which, *.vcf.gz exists. 

* = unique alphanumeric idenitifier. This identifier is consistent between the tar ball and the .vcf.gz file. 

Output directory can be anything. Lets call it ./output_vcfs

Comment: I don't understand your description, but suspect **GNU Parallel** can do it. Example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50924295/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the tar files in the directory and then perform the tar command on each file.

```
for i in *tar.gz;
do 
   tar -xvf "$i" -C "/path/to/new/folder" "*.vcf.gz";    # Use -C to switch directory before extract and put extension to search for in tar file in quotes.
done
```